# Deleting decimals from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have numbers such as

```
24.00

2.00

3.00
```

I want to have

```
24 

2 

3
```

I have used .astype(int), round() but I keep getting the former. How do I get this to work?

Comment: Do you have missing values in your data?  In pandas dataframes, only float-type columns may have missing data.

Comment: It's probably because you have `None` or `nan` in your column. In which case, the column type is always `float`.

Comment: Also, be aware that instead of astype(int) pandas will work better if you use astype(np.int64) (or np.int32, np.int16, etc. depending on what's appropriate for your data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-assign `dataframe`
(which is, what I suppose your error is):

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data={"col": [24.00, 2.00, 3.00]})
>>> df.dtypes
col    float64
dtype: object
>>> df
    col
0  24.0
1   2.0
2   3.0
>>> df=df.astype(int)
>>> df
   col
0   24
1    2
2    3
>>> df.dtypes
col    int32
dtype: object
```

Comment: I believe OP already tried `astype(int)` and it did not work.

Comment: I did not set df = df.astype(int) originally, this now works

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by setting the pandas `option`, `precision` to 0.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"col": [24.00, 2.00, 3.00]})
print(df)
    col
0  24.0
1   2.0
2   3.0
pd.set_option('precision',0)
print(df)
   col
0   24
1    2
2    3
```